# How can I add the information after the element but not its content easily?

Tags: html, css

I use the `:after` to add the content after the div, but you know it will add to the div's text, but not add next to the div's border.

```css
#div2 {

    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: beige;
}

#div2:after {

    content: "a";
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="div2">
    div2-text
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Can I easily add the border after the div's frame(you can see the div's background-color)?

Comment: You have to position it, otherwise it gets added before (:before) or after (:after) the content of the element

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```css
#div2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: beige;
}

#div2:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 5px;
  right: -5px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="div2">
    div2-text
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't think this is out of the div.

Comment: @s-n-2 I understood that you are looking to make the `:after` by the border of the div. The `a` inside the `:after` is outside, by the border of the div. Did I understand your question wrong?

Comment: The content should on the div's right, you set the `:after` background-color you can see the content still in the div, but not out of the div.

Comment: @s-n-2 See my edit and check out if this is what you mean.

Comment: you see, the `:after`'s content still in the div, not out of the div.

Comment: @s-n-2 Well, this is my last try to understand what you mean. Check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend to create another empty div after your div where you have the content, a solution with absolute position is not good/useful, because you will have more things on your website and then they will be on top of your "a" text or whatever text you will add with :after.
So just create another div :-)

Answer (score 0):

Put the text in a `span` and apply `:after` to the `span`

```css
#div2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: beige;
}

#div2 span:after {
  content: "after";
}
```

```html
<div id="div2">
  <span>div2-text</span>
</div>
```